# Project Server and MAXDOP

Tags: sql-server, project-server

SharePoint 2013 and 2016 requires MAXDOP to be set to 1, but I can't find recommendations for the Project Server database(s). Should project server databases be on a separate instance to take advantage of a different MAXDOP setting? Or if they are moved to a different instance, should that instance also be configed with MAXDOP=1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They carry the same requirement as MAXDOP = 1, especially now that in 2016 the Project schema resides within the content databases.